# C++ polymorphism with template interface

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

Timer.h:

```
template<class T>
class Timer {
    public:
      typedef T Units;

    virtual Units get() = 0;
};
```

TimerImpl.h:

```
class TimerImpl: public Timer<long> {
public:

TimerImpl() {
}

~TimerImpl() {

}

long get();

};
```

FpsMeter.h(version 1):

```
template <class T> 
class FpsMeter {
    private:
    Timer<T>* timer;

    public:
    FpsMeter (Timer<T>* timer) {
        this->timer = timer;
    }

    ...

};
```

This example works. But it does not look pretty.

```
Timer<long>* t = new TimerImpl();
FpsMeter<long>* f1  = new FpsMeter<long> (t);
```

Here there are a lot of extra template uses. How can I realize this idea of multy-type interface when the type is defined by the implementation and user class has not to define new type, it should use the type of the implementation.

Comment: Is there any *reason* for the separate interface `Timer<T>`?

Comment: If you want a version of the interface with get() returning different types then template is the way to do it AFAIU.

Comment: @Kerrek SB yes, there is. I want to use different timers.

Comment: Timer doesn't actually have an polymorphic behavior, just a different interface.  Why not make (or reuse) a concrete timer and write some helper functions to get the right unit?

Comment: In C++11, you can get rid of one of the template names by writing `auto f1 = new FpsMeter<long>(t);` If you use `auto` for `t`, it will get the type `TimerImpl*` which may or may not be a problem.

Comment: You can use TimerImpl::Units instead of long for more flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind a helper template function which always creates FpsMeter on the heap you could something like the following

```
template < class T >
FpsMeter<T> *make_FpsMeter( Timer<T> *timer ) {
  return new FpsMeter<T>( timer );
  }
```

Then creating a FpsMeter of the appropriate type is like so

```
FpsMeter<long> *f1 = make_FpsMeter( new TimerImpl() );
```

Or if you can use C++11 auto you'd get

```
auto f1 = make_FpsMeter( new TimerImpl() );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best you can do in C++, as far as I know.  `FpsCounter` needs to know the type `T` so that it knows which `Timer<T>` implementations it can accept.  Your sample code can be made somewhat simpler:

```
FpsMeter<long>* f1  = new FpsMeter<long> (new TimerImpl());
```

...which at least gets you out of repeating the template type, but of course in that case `FpsMeter` must take responsibility for deleting the `TimerImpl`, ideally through an `auto_ptr` or such.

I'd question, too, whether you really need to vary the return value of `get()`.  What sorts of values do you expect it to return, besides `long`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can take inspiration from the [`<chrono>` library](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm) from C++11 (also available in boost). Or better yet, save yourself some time and just use it directly. It's efficient, safe, flexible, and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only timers based on implementation of machine timer (which should be defined at compilation stage for entire program I assume), i would simply use `typedef` and perhaps some preprocessor magic to get it right:

```
[...]
#if TIMER_LONG // Here you should somehow check what type is used on target platform.
    typedef Timer<long> implTimer;
    typedef FpsMeter<long> implFpsMeter;
#else // If eg. using double?
    typedef Timer<double> implTimer;
    typedef FpsMeter<double> implFpsMeter;
#fi
```

This should make user code unaware of actual typee used, as long it is using implTimer and implFpsMeter.

If you mean that some parts of code will use different TimerImpl then you should make your `FpsMeter` class polymorphic

```
class FpsMeter{
public:
    virtual double fps()=0;
    virutal void newFrame()=0;
    [...]
    //Class counts new frames and using internal timer calculates fps.
};

template <typename T>
class FpsMeterImpl: public FpsMeter{
    TimerImpl<T>* timer;
public:
    FpsMeterImpl(TimerImpl<T>* timer);

    virtual double fps();
    virutal void newFrame();
};
```